# Index Match using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lookup

I have the following 2 excel files:

df1.xlsx:

SETTLED_BILL_ID APPROVED_BY BILL_DESCRIPTION    BILLED_AMOUNT   BILL_CONTROL_NUMBER

56006427    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749361

55111860    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749370

56606452    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749376

55163447    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749378

55213501    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749380

55094012    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749381

55739677    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749382

55191825    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749383

55952559    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749387

58316565    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749390

55094013    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749392

55262079    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749394

58148764    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749397

55314522    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749399

55192521    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749398

55216501    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749400

58769648    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749403

55236840    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749404

56062780    111 Loan Application    30000   991110770598

58778154    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749406

55596936    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749409

and df2.xlsx

id  appcategory sname   sex app_year    paid_status BILL_CONTROL_NUMBER

206348  1   MSAGATI M   2020    1   991110749361

206349  1   MWANSELE    M   2020    1   991110749370

206350  1   MWAKO   M   2020    1   991110749376

206351  1   DISMAS  M   2020    1   991110749364

206352  1   NYANDWI M   2020    1   991110749365

206353  1   THADEUS M   2020    1   991110749366

206354  1   MAKOBA  M   2020    1   991110749367

206355  1   MACHA   M   2020    1   991110749368

206356  1   BAISHE  F   2020    1   991110749392

206357  1   ANUWAR  M   2020    1   991110749394

206358  1   SOSPETER    M   2020    1   991110749397

206360  1   SHEMAHONGE  M   2020    1   991110749373
206362  1   NGOGO   M   2020    1   991110749375

206363  1   FARANGA M   2020    1   991110749376

206364  1   ADOLF   M   2020    1   991110749377

206365  1   ELIAS   M   2020    1   991110749378

206367  1   SABRI   M   2020    1   991110749380

206368  1   JOHN    M   2020    1   991110770598

206369  1   LUGANGA M   2020    1   991110749406

206370  1   HUCHE   M   2020    1   991110749383

I want to check if all BILL_CONTROL_NUMBER from df1 are present in df2

It can be solved using the Index + Match  functionality of excel. What shall be the best way to replicate it in Pandas.

Desired Output: add a new column 'RESULTS'

SETTLED_BILL_ID APPROVED_BY BILL_DESCRIPTION    BILLED_AMOUNT   BILL_CONTROL_NUMBER RESULTS

56006427    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749361    TRUE

55111860    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749370    TRUE

56606452    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749376    TRUE

55163447    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749378    TRUE

55213501    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749380    TRUE

55094012    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749381    FALSE

55739677    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749382    FALSE

55191825    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749383    TRUE

55952559    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749387    FALSE

58316565    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749390    FALSE

55094013    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749392    TRUE

55262079    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749394    TRUE

58148764    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749397    TRUE

55314522    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749399    FALSE

55192521    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749398    FALSE

55216501    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749400    FALSE

58769648    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749403    FALSE

55236840    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749404    FALSE

56062780    111 Loan Application    30000   991110770598    TRUE

58778154    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749406    TRUE

55596936    111 Loan Application    30000   991110749409    FALSE

Equivalent Excel formula `=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(E2,$F$2:$F$21,0)))`

[Link to df1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rjsn-jotq96rYRbvlEKj8Xe7ug8BklwN/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100970845094450129298&rtpof=true&sd=true)

[Link to df2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KwiN5SvTCgZuN8xqdA8hAIr5wzZlvEi1/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100970845094450129298&rtpof=true&sd=true)

[Link to desired output](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DSkuj80zWWFBSl3GuiY1MpcE-QpD8VMJ/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100970845094450129298&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: Use `df1['new'] = df1['BILL_CONTROL_NUMBER'].isin(df2['BILL_CONTROL_NUMBER'])`

Comment: Thanks, it's what i have been looking for